# Unable to install HAXM in Windows 10

Tags: windows, operating-system

I'm working on android studio when I run the application it shows an error when I tried to install emulator through sdk it shows
ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
I'm using Windows 10 and it does not have hyper - v so I'm unable to install HAXM .please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this issue before on OSX.

How I fixed it:  Delete/Reinstall the Android SDK.  Sometimes if you install the SDK in a different location then it was before, may help as well.

Also you could check and see if you need to install any new updates in the SDK it's self.